# Inserting character into string using recursion? (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to take a user inputted character, and insert it into a string in the right alphabetical place using recursion, and then ask for another character. Only one character should be inputted at a time.

I thought a good way was to scan throught the string, and when the inputted chracter matches the chracter in the alphabet string, to then insert it. But I'm having trouble putting that into code. I also must use recursion (the stack, $jal, $jr $ra) but I'm not totally familiar with how to use it like that.

Here is my code so far:

```
        .data

    str: .asciiz "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz .space 30" 
    input: .asciiz "Please input a letter: "
    error1: .asciiz "Error! Please only enter one lowercase letter!"
    print1: .asciiz "The string is: "


    .text

    main:
    la $s0,0
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,input
    syscall

    loop:
    li $v0,8
    syscall
    move $t0,$v0
    blt $t0,61,error #if less than a
    bgt $t0,80,error #if more than z
    bge $t0,0x50,print #when user enters P, print

    loop2:
    lb $t2,str($s0) #load first byte of string
    bge $t0,$t2,store #if input char=string char, store it
    addi $s0,$s0,1 #next char in string
    j loop

    store:
    sw $t0,str($s0) #store char in string
    addi $s0,$s0,1 #next char in string
    j loop

    error:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,error1 #print error message
    syscall
    j loop #jump back to loop

    print:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,print1 #print dialogue
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,str #print string
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

Before addressing anything else, you need to make clear how exactly this inserting is supposed to work. You are to take a character and insert it into a pre-existing string, correct? If so, then that would mean you need to create a modifiable buffer filled with the string. The `.space` directive will do. Furthermore, you need to allocate a large buffer since you'll be inserting characters. And lastly, inserting characters means shifting, so prepare yourself for that.

Currently, you have:

```
str: .asciiz "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

I'm guessing that you're going to modify that string, but string declarations aren't meant to be modified. You probably could modify it and even make your program work, but I don't recommend going about it that way. If you declare multiple strings (and you do), it's likely they'll be placed contiguously, and you'd then be overwriting data. I'd focus on getting all that worked out before attempting to ask the user for input.

Then you have the following:

```
loop:
    li $v0,8
    syscall
    move $t0,$v0
```

`syscall 8` reads a string, not a character. `syscall 12` reads a character. And in your attempt to read a string from the console, you didn't provide a buffer address in `$a0`. Then you attempt to move the result of the system call into a temporary register, but the call doesn't return anything. It only places the input-string into the buffer.